# NSUserDefaults not loading string array

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults

Before anyone says that its a question thats been asked many times before, i've gone through about 20 different answers and tried everything I found. Despite this, I only started objective c about 5 days ago, so there is probably some really simple solution.

It appears that NSUserDefaults does not load an array from the default property list, despite being called to in many different ways. Before i go on, here is my code for reading the array :

```
      fishArrayMutable = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:(NSArray*)[defaults objectForKey:@"fishArray"] copyItems:TRUE];

     if (fishArrayMutable == nil)
     {
       fishArrayMutable =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
       [alert setTitle:@"fishArray = nil"];
       [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Ok"];
       [alert show];
       [alert release];
     }
```

And here is my code for writing the array :

```
[defaults setObject:fishArrayMutable forKey:@"fishArray"];

[defaults synchronize];
```

This is starting to become a very frustrating problem now, and i've gone about ways of isolating the problem, and reached the conclusion that its in the reading part. The Mutable array is declared in the header file. Please help, this has been bugging me for about 6 hours now...

Comment: What kind of objects do you put into fishArray?

Comment: Strings, the names of your fish.. Theres also an array called fishSizeArray which is identical

Comment: I am jumbled here. When are u setting object to defaults? before you allocate it..?? coz you are allocating fishArrayMutable & same time u r asking for that fishArrayMutable stored in defaults. So i am confused..!! Pls help me if I am missing anything

Comment: No i allocate and read the values in the array in one method, then write them much later, the writing bit is fine, but the reading bit doesnt work, it crashes my app. The writing the array bit comes 4 or 5 method calls down the line.

Comment: Generally `synchronize` is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that the error is one of:

1. `defaults` is not initialized.
2. The userDefaults are not set prior to reading
3. the userDefaults are over written prior reading.

Break every step down and write tests before and after each step.

1) `NSLog` `fishArrayMutable` where it is written to verify the array contents.
2) Immediatly after writing `fishArrayMutable` to defaults `NSLog` the user defaults.
Example:

```
NSLog(@"Before writing fishArray: %@", fishArrayMutable);
[defaults setObject:fishArrayMutable forKey:@"fishArray"];
NSLog(@"After writing fishArray: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"fishArray"]);
```

Note that the `NSLog` statements do *not* use `defaults` keeping them self contained.

Do similar `NSLog` statements bracketing the read (and make the read two statements):

```
NSLog(@"Before reading fishArray: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"fishArray"]);
NSArray *fishArray = [defaults objectForKey:@"fishArray"];
NSLog(@"After reading fishArray: %@", fishArray);
fishArrayMutable = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:fishArray copyItems:TRUE];
NSLog(@"After creating fishArrayMutable: %@", fishArrayMutable);
```

Then the problem should be rather obvious.

Note: since the array items themselves will be immutable due to `NSUserDefaults` instead of:
`fishArrayMutable = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:fishArray copyItems:TRUE];`
you should be able to just use `mutableCopy`:
`fishArrayMutable = [fishArray mutableCopy];`

Answer (score 1):

Try Using `mutableArrayValueForKey` check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Use it like this:

```
fishArrayMutable = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[defaults mutableArrayValueForKey:@"fishArray"]];
```

it works for me

**EDIT**:

writing:

```
[defaults setObject:fishArrayMutable forKey:@"fishArray"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

load:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [defaults mutableArrayValueForKey:@"fishArray"];
```

Comment: Did you try loading the array like I indicated?? I load a mutablearray like this and never had problems .. actually is in AppStore

Comment: There is no problem, but the class is interesting and not what one would expect: ` NSLog(@"array className: %@", NSStringFromClass([array class]));` is `NSKeyValueSlowMutableArray`.